# Sort text in a div alphabetically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, alphabetical

Is it possible to find some particular text in a `div` and then sort it alphabetically?

For example, in this block of text in a `div`:

```
<div class="text-block">
Jim, Mike, Ali, and Marsha went to the store.
</div>
```

I'd want to have `Jim, Mike, Ali, and Marsha` be ordered alphabetically so the output would be this instead:

```
<div class="text-block">
Ali, Jim, Marsha, and Mike went to the store.
</div>
```

I feel that's pretty much impossible outright, but maybe just a find and replace instead? Not too sure on what the best method would be.

Comment: Will you always have four people or the number of people would vary?

Comment: As written, this problem isn't easy. Try to break it down into smaller chunks. You can use jQuery to get the text inside the div. Then, using regex's, you can find every word that's capitalized and put those words into an array. Sort that array and then reformat the names into the beginning of a sentence. Then put them back into the div. Not easy, but doable.

Comment: Possible, but probably not something anyone would want to write. Can you not store the names in a pre-sorted variable and write it out?

Comment: it's bit hard because of  `and Marsha went to the store.`. Also is the format will always same? 4 names with `, and  went to the store`?

Comment: To give this some more context, it was a discussion with a friend of mine and the data is coming from a JSON feed that is getting parsed out by PHP. Overall, it's not the epic "end of the world" thing, but we were wonder if there was some way to accomplish it with not having to do a find and replace. But I think that a find and replace might be the only way.

Comment: Basically you're asking "Is it possible to parse natural human language?" and you're getting a  bunch of answers below that are all "Sure! Throw a regex at it! Split it on commas!" Which is great until the next bit of text you try to parse omits the Oxford comma or uses  any of the zillions of other grammatical variations humans tend to use in plain text. There's a reason natural language processing is an entire field of study. It's hard.

Comment: @DanielBeck agreed with you.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with regex.  This way you can support more versatile input.

```js
$(".text-block").html(function(idx, oldhtml) {
    return oldhtml.replace(/[, a-z]+and [a-z]+/gi,function(a) {
        tmp = a.replace(" and "," ").split(/[^\w]+/).sort();
        return tmp.slice(0,-1).join(", ") + ", and " + tmp.pop();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-block">
Jim, Mike, Ali, and Marsha went to the store.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that :

```
divText = $('.text-block').text();
arr = divText.split(",");
lastStr = arr.pop(-1);
arr.sort();
arr.push(lastStr);
$('.text-block').text(arr.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
Use regex to get the names starting from capital letter.
Remaining text needs to be concatenated after sorting names.
See below:

```js
var str = $('.text-block').text();//Read the div

var names = str.match(/\b[A-Z].*?\b/g);//Find out names

var lastName = names[names.length - 1];
var lastNameIndex = str.indexOf(lastName);
var remainingStr = str.slice(lastNameIndex + lastName.length);//remaining 
                                                              //text
names = names.sort();
names[names.length - 1] = " and " + names[names.length - 1];
var newStr = names + remainingStr;
$('.text-block').text(newStr);//update div
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-block">
  Jim, Mike, Ali, and Marsha went to the store.
</div>
```